# R script to perl?

Tags: r, perl, ld

I have an R script I want to use to parse a file and get some info out of it, but the file is 44 GB.

Can someone help me write this in a programming language that is faster in reading files?

The script is pretty simple:

```
ld <- read.table("plink-inter-chr---ld-window-r2-0.ld", header = T)
ldv1 <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(ld[,1]), "_"))
ldv4 <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(ld[,4]), "_"))
ld <- matrix(c(ldv1[,2], ldv4[,2], ld[,2], ld[,5], ld[,7]), ncol=5)
N <- 30
within <- numeric(N)
between <- numeric(N)
for(i in 1:N){
within[i] <- mean(as.numeric(ld[which(ld[,1] == i & ld[,2] == i),5]))
between[i] <- mean(as.numeric(ld[which(ld[,1] == i & ld[,2] != i),5]))
}
table <- matrix(c(within, between), ncol=2)
write.table(table, file = "within-between.tab", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

And the file looks as such:

```
 CHR_A         BP_A SNP_A  CHR_B         BP_B SNP_B           R2           DP
NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97          919    . NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97         2210    .            1            1
NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97          919    . NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97         2419    .            1            1
NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97          919    . NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97         2524    .            1            1
NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97          919    . NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97         2587    .            1            1
NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97          919    . NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97         2799    .            1            1
NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97          919    . NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97         2947    .            1            1
NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97          919    . NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97         3142    .            1            1
NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97          919    . NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97         3178    .            1            1
NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97          919    . NODE_1_length_193190_coverage_19.3759_GC_24.97         3261    .            1            1
```

Thank you for your help,
Adrian

Comment: For those not fluent in R, can you give an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: @AdrianP: What does your *"Can someone help me write this in a programming language that is faster in reading files"* mean? What languages do you know, and what help do you need? I imagine this is to do with your employment, and it would be very wrong of you to use and be paid for anyone else's efforts

Comment: http://mysite.science.uottawa.ca/ncorradi/members.html I am doing my masters in science. I do get a bursary for doing my masters, but it is not employment in the traditional sense. I know a bit of perl and python.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the places in the R code that you are wasting time and being slowed down (and therefore could speed things up quite a bit) include:

You are reading character strings, converting them to factors, then converting them back to character strings.  Look at the `stringsAsFactors` argument to `read.table` for how to avoid both conversions.

While you are at it, you may be able to gain some speed by specifying `colClasses` in `read.table` so that the function does not need to waste time guessing what each column should be.

After doing the string split you `rbind` everything together, but then only use 1 column from each of the resulting matrices.  It may be quicker to just grab the number (or sequence of non "*") after the first "*", you can use the `strapply` function from the gsubfn package or just the `regexpr` and `regmatches` functions.

Using the `cbind` function to create the ld matrix may be faster than concatenating then rewrapping using `matrix`.  Actually, why create the matrix in the first place, you don't use 2 of the columns and the others are used separately.  This also converts your numeric to character that just need to be converted back later.

Running `as.numeric` in the loop is inefficient, you keep converting the same values over and over again, just do a single `as.numeric` on the whole matrix before the loop.

You don't need the calls to `which` since subscripting works fine on the logicals that `which` works on.

Fix the above and see how much that speeds up the results.